# Solving the PDE $v_x + v_y = 1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, transport-equation

I have $v_x + v_y = 1$.

It's obvious that $v(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ works as a solution, but I need to find a general solution to this PDE.  What can I do?

I have tried doing a substitution, to no avail.  Perhaps I am over thinking this problem and there is some really simple solution to a non-homogenous PDE like this one that my book doesn't discuss.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup the method of characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

That is an inhomogeneous transport equation. You need to use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) to solve it. Basically, this method seeks curves along which the PDE becomes an ordinary differential equation.

Assume your solution is of the form $v(x,y)=v(x,Y(x))=V(x)$, where $Y$ is a characteristic curve of the solution. Then,
$$\frac{d}{dx}V(x)=v_x(x,Y(x))+v_y(x,Y(x))\ Y'(x).$$
So, if you pick $Y$ such that $Y'(x)=1$, you get that
$$\frac{d}{dx}V(x)=v_x(x,Y(x))+v_y(x,Y(x)) = 1.$$
And that is a much easier ODE you can solve.

Therefore, you just need to follow three steps:

1. Find the characteristic by solving $Y'(X)=1$ with the *final* condition $Y(x)=y$.
2. Determine the solution along a characteristic by solving $V'(X)=1$ with the initial condition $V(0)=V(0,Y(0))=0$ (or any other initial condition you might have).
3. Find the solution at the endpoint of the characteristic, $v(x,y)=V(x)$, which is the solution of the PDE at $(x,y)$.

You can find plenty of notes on this topic by googling. For instance, check [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math456/characteristics.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Note that Lagrange's form $P(x,y,v)p+Q(x,y,v)q=R(x,y,v)$ for which the subsidiary equations are

$$\frac{dx}{P}=\frac{dy}{Q}=\frac{dv}{R}$$

In your case, $P=Q=R=1$, so it is easy to obtain $v-x=c_1$ and $y-x=c_2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants of integration. Combining these two, you get $v-x=f(y-x)$ or  $v=f(y-x)+x$ as the general solution for an arbitrary function $f$.